# C#: GetCreationTime and GetLastWriteTime gave same time, but my file size is increasing over the time

Tags: c#

I created a performan file (.blg) and started the performance parameters collection.

The file Modified Date never updated on windows explorer, it is always showing up the Created Date like below, but over the time the file size is increasing.

[image]

Now I would like to get the file created data and last write date, but below code gave me same date/time (the created time). How to get last write time of the file?

```
Console.WriteLine(File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Temp\BasicPerfCounters.blg"));

Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Temp\BasicPerfCounters.blg"));
```

Comment: So is it being modified by the process?

Comment: Yes, it's modified by process only

Answer (score 0):

The answer from MSDN:

> This method may return an **inaccurate value**, because it uses native
>   functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the
>   operating system. Each operating system manages the last write time
>   according to its own rules. **To improve performance, an operating
>   system might not set the last write time value to the exact time** of
>   the last write operation, but might set it to a close approximation
>   instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx

So it seems that OS is not changing the Last Write Time for performance consideration. This is especially valid since the process seems to update the file very frequently and the OS is not intended to update the file Last Write Time accordingly.

Therefore, I suggest to save the last update time in an in-memory variable or even in database. However, the best way I think is to get the Last Write Time from the your performance file (.blg) that you are using.

Note: if you need to read the data form the .blg problematically (including the Last Write Time of the last action saved), you may consider changing the format to a Comma-Separated Value for example using the tool: RELOG.EXE. [And here is Two Minute Drill article: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/05/20/two-minute-drill-relog-exe/](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/05/20/two-minute-drill-relog-exe/).